# MYSQL Check if every item that exists within one table, exists in another

Tags: mysql

How can I check if all the items in one table exists within another. For example, consider the following two tables.

With their respective query:

```
SELECT orderID
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 1;

TABLE A
-------

orderID
2
1
6
4
```

```
SELECT orderID
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 2;

TABLE B
-------

orderID
5
1
7
9
```

I would not want to output anything because all the items from TABLE A do not exist within TABLE B.

However, I were to have:

```
SELECT orderID
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 3;

TABLE C
-------

orderID
5
```

I would want to output it because all the items within TABLE C are in TABLE B.

If I were to do a select with TABLE C, I would expect table C to be the output.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT orderID
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 1) A
WHERE A.orderID IN (
SELECT orderID
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = 2);
```

Comment: So if table B does not contain ALL elements from table A, you don't want any data? And what do you want returned for table C? You are not specifying even what you would select. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You could use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the `orderID` values and then you can simply run one comparison. Both sides should be ordered the same way. I'm not sure if there are many pitfalls on this method, but your query overall seems like not a great way of doing things. . . . .

Comment: @Andrew I have just updated the question, let me know if this helps.

Comment: And your query parameters will be just those two customer ids?

Comment: Still there, @APorter1031?

Comment: Yes, your answer sufficed and I accepted it. Params are JUST those two customer ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can to check in a by-customer basis, you can do this:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS
    SELECT NULL
    FROM orders
    WHERE customer_id = 1 -- "Table A"
    AND orderID NOT IN 
        -- "Table B"
        (SELECT orderID
        FROM orders
        WHERE customer_id = 2)
    )
    SELECT orderID
    FROM orders
    WHERE customer_id = 1;
```

Here the query basically gets the orders from table A which are not in table B. If there is none, it then performs the select at the end. Otherwise, it does nothing.

If you use `customer_id = 3` instead, you get one row with orderID 5 ("table C").

Comment: Is there a way to write this query where I don't need to explicitly set customer_id values and just iterate over all of them?

Comment: And which is the customer_id to compare to? Always 2?

Comment: Both of the ids are dynamic as they are from rows with pairs. My problem is now that my WHERE clause does not know the cust1 and cust2 variables that I have declared up top.

Comment: So you need all possible combinations of two customer_ids? Do you need the results in one query or many queries?

Comment: I have the combinations, I need the result of which combinations yield a result, like table 3 did.

Comment: By "I have the combinations", do you mean there is another table? An option could be to make this a SP and call it with each combination.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to left join a table with TABLE B and look for nulls in the resulting sub-query. Here is some (untested) pseudo code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
 SELECT 
 table_B.orderID 
 FROM table_A 
 LEFT JOIN table_B ON table_A.orderID=table_B.orderID 
) x WHERE x.orderID IS NULL
```

Any rows from table_A that don't have a match in table_B will have a NULL value as table_B.orderID. The outer select you may have to change depending on what type of output you are looking for, but hopefully the principal helps.

Comment: Unrelated question: what did you use to write this? Each line ends with hundreds of spaces (check the horizontal scroll bar).

Comment: Apologies, it was a quick copy/paste from a terminal editor, and I attempted to delete the trailing whitespace but the SO editor must not select all the way to the end of the line.